# Overflow in SML

Tags: overflow, sml

I am writing a program in SML that takes as an argument an integer N, but for inputs higher than 537070910 it gives me this error: uncaught exception Overflow [overflow].

Any ideas why?

Comment: It's very difficult to guess what your program does that causes this unless you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

> for inputs higher than 537070910 it gives me this error: uncaught exception Overflow

You would probably have to say what *it* is in "*it* gives me this error".

The integer 537070910 itself fits within the 30 bits that Standard ML typically has for an *int*'s magnitude:

```
- Int.maxInt;
val it = SOME 1073741823 : int option
```

So perhaps *it* produces a value above `Int.maxInt`.

Depending on what SML compiler you're using, you may want to either benefit from 64-bit integers or arbitrary-sized integers in the event that your function is dealing with numbers close to the edge.

*(If you revise your question to be more specific, I will revise this answer likewise.)*